# Incorrect image on visa

Tags: visas, uae

I applied for a UAE 90-day visit visa. The visa came out but has a different image. Not my picture but another person's picture. What should I do? Can I travel with it that way?

Comment: Did you ask the consulate that issued the visa? What did they say?

Comment: Don't travel on that visa if you don't want to risk detention at the airport. Apply for correction before traveling to UAE.

Comment: Travelling is risky, contact your consulate immediately

Answer (score 5):

Do not travel on a visa that shows someone else's picture. You're likely to at least be detained while the situation is investigated, could be refused entry and sent back, or worse, potentially accused of a crime for trying to use someone else's visa.

There must have been some kind of mistake at the consulate. You should contact the office that issued you the visa and ask that they correct the error.